# 単項演算子の結合順序の意味について

Tags: c

四則演算の演算子や代入演算子など二項演算子については
結合順序(左から右、右から左)が意味をなす場面が想像しやすいのですが、
単項演算子の結合順序が意味をなす場面が想像しにくいです。

どのような場合に意味があるのでしょうか？

例えば、単項マイナスは

```
-1-1
```

の場面に結合順序が意味をなしそうですが、
実際には後者のマイナスは二項演算子のマイナスで、
優先順位(単項マイナス>二項演算子の減算)に従っているだけなので、
単項マイナスの結合順序はこの場合関係無いと思われます。

また、同様にインクリメント、デクリメント演算子の結合順序がどのような時に意味があるのか良く分かりません。

x++が「評価してから1加える」のと、
++xが「1加えてから評価する」という違いに現れているのかとも思いましたが、
C言語入門 (ASCII SOFTWARE SCIENCE Language)によると、
「結合順序は優先順位が同一順位の演算子をCが評価する時の順序」
としているので、この場合には当てはまらないと考えられます。

Comment: 参考 (本家 Stack Overflow 上の類似質問です): ["Does it make sense for unary operators to be associative?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12961351/5989200)

Comment: 参考 (本家 Stack Overflow 上の類似質問です): ["Is there such thing as a left-associative prefix operator or right-associative postfix operator?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14084421/5989200)

Comment: 有難うございます。このリンク先を元に自己回答してみます。

Answer (score 2):

単項演算子が２つ以上重ねられた際に意味があるのでは？

```
int i = 10;
printf("%d\n", !!i);
```

`i`が評価され`10`が得られます。次に`!i`で`0`になります。最後に`!!i`で`1`になります。自然な流れになるように前置単項演算子は右から、後置単項演算子は左からとなっているだけかと。

Comment: 回答有難うございます。言われてみれば、-1は単項演算子じゃなくて普通に整数ですね。削除しておきます。

Comment: 確かに!を重ねた時には意味がありますね。インクリメントなど重ねられないものはこういった重ねられるものに単純に合わせただけで実際に結合順序を使う場面は無いという事でしょうか？

Comment: @sayuri さん、細かいですが `!!0` ではなく `!0` ではないでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さんありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り誤っていましたので訂正しました。

Comment: @user25791  「-1で一つの整数」 _integer-constant_ に`-`のシンボルは含まれませんので、符号付き整数ではなく単項演算子です。 [C11 ドラフト 6.4.4 Constants](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) を参照ください。

Comment: コメント有難うございます。-1は単項演算子のマイナスではないと言われて納得してしまいましたが、実は単項演算子だったのですね。元々の文章に戻します。

Comment: ちなみに、6.4.4.1のsyntaxの部分の
「decimal-constant: 
nonzero-digit 
decimal-constant digit」
nonzero-digitとdecimal-constant digitは改行で分けられてますが別に区切っている訳ではなく
「10進数の定数はゼロじゃない数の後ろに10進数の定数が続く」という意味で問題無いですよね？
単純に見やすくするためかと思うのですが、その上にある「integer-constant」では改行は区切りに使われているので、
このような仕様書を初めて見る私としてはちょっと違和感を感じてしまいました。

Comment: 例えば8bit符号あり整数で`-128`が表現できなくなってしまう（正の`128`が8bitを超えてしまうため）のでマイナス符号も定数に含まれているのかと勘違いしていました。この辺り言語ごとに異なるんですね。 @BLUEPIXY さん勉強になりました。

Comment: @user25791  「10進数の定数はゼロじゃない数の後ろに10進数の定数が続く」という意味で問題無いです。 この2行については文法規則のOR条件のようなものになります。 一行目が成立する時（つまり１文字の１～９の時）それで10進数の定数であり、二行目はそのことを含めた再帰的な定義で、二行目が成立する時もまた10進数の定数であるということになります。 リプライされる時にはコメントの最初に＠に続けてユーザー名をつけるとメッセージボックスに表示されるので、リプライがあったことがわかるようになっています。そのようにして頂くといいかと思います。（でないとリプライがあったことがわかるとは限りません）

Comment: @sayuri 例えば`limits.h`の`INT_MIN`などを見て頂くと、`(-INT_MAX-1)`とかなっていたり(もちろん実装依存)してその点を苦心するところがみてとれます。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY あ、decimal-constant digitで10進数の定数と思ってました。二行目はくどく言えば、decimal-constant decimal-digitって事ですね。@はリンクされてないのでいまいち機能が良く分からなくて使ってませんでした。これから使います。コメント有難うございました。

Comment: @user25791 `digit` は、`6.4.2.1 General`の部分で定義(_one of
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9_)されていて(0が含まれる数値文字の意味)、既出ということです。

Comment: @user25791  コメントのリプライについて詳しくは、[これ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply) を御覧下さい。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 既出だったのですね。コメントのリプライの方も参考になりました。有難うございました。

Answer (score 1):

nekketsuuuさんのコメントのリンク先を元に自己回答してみます。
他にもコメントがあれば、修正していきたいので、何か意見があればお願いします。

インクリメント、デクリメントでは例えば

```
++*y
```

のような場合に結合順序が意味をなす。(prefixの++も*も同じ優先順位)

左結合ならば

```
(++*)y
```

と同義となる。

この場合、*がオペランドとして++を許容するか、もしくは++*という右結合のオペレーターが無い限りエラーになる。

一方、右結合ならば

```
++(*y)
```

と同義となる。

実際*と++は右結合なので、ポインタ先の変数をインクリメントして評価する事になる。

Answer (score 0):

単項演算子の場合は、演算子の対象が片側にしかないのですから、その対象側から結合するしかありません。例えば、間接演算子 `*` で`*p` と書いたとき、左結合にしたくても、左側にはオペランドがないので、結合しようがありません。